# How to Upsert Multiple childs with SOAP or REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, integration

I have an opportunity and child objects customobj1 and customobj2. I need to update the opportunity and upsert the child objects customobj1 and customobj2. It seems there is a limitation where we cannot update/usert multiple objects in a soap api upsert call according to salesforce documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-soap-api-sample-wsdls.html).
I have also tried to use the REST API but did not find a way to update it. This is json I have used with patch

```
      {
    "records" :[{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
    "name" : "SampleAccount",
    "phone" : "1234567890",
    "website" : "www.salesforce.com",
    "id"       : "0016300000NOteE",
    "numberOfEmployees" : "100",
    "type" : "Analyst",
    "industry" : "Banking",
    "Contacts" : {
      "records" : [{
         "attributes" : {"type" : "Contact", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
         "lastname" : "Smith",
         "title" : "President",
         "email" : "sample@salesforce.com"
         },{         
         "attributes" : {"type" : "Contact", "referenceId" : "ref3"},
         "lastname" : "Evans",
         "title" : "Vice President",
         "email" : "sample@salesforce.com"
         }]
      },
    "Opportunities" : {
      "records" : [{
         "attributes" : {"type" : "Opportunity", "referenceId" : "ref4"},
         "Name" : "Test Opty",
         "StageName" : "Prospecting",
         "CloseDate" : "2018-03-19"
         }]
      }
    }]
}
```

I have updated code as suggested by Daniel like this

```
 {
    "allOrNone" : true,
    "compositeRequest" : [{
        "method" : "PATCH",
        "url" : "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Account/001i000002CPZlD",
        "referenceId" : "UpdatedAccount",
        "body" : {  
            "Name" : "SampleAccount",
            "Phone" : "7702345678"
        }
    },{
        "method" : "PATCH",
        "referenceId" : "NewContact",
        "url" : "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Contact/",
        "body" : {  
            "lastname" : "Smithchanged",
            "title" : "President",
            "email" : "sample@salesforce.com",
            "con_ext_id__c" : "c222",
            "AccountId" : "001i000002CPZlD"
        }
    },{
        "method" : "PATCH",
        "referenceId" : "NewContact2",
        "url" : "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Contact/",
        "body" : {  
            "lastname" : "Evanschanged",
            "title" : "Vice President",
            "email" : "sample@salesforce.com",
            "con_ext_id__c" : "c111",
            "AccountId" : "001i000002CPZlD"
        }
    },{
        "method" : "PATCH",
        "referenceId" : "opportunity1",
        "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/opportunity",
        "body" : {  
            "Name" : "Test Optyone Changed",
            "StageName" : "Prospecting",
            "CloseDate" : "2018-03-19",
            "opty_ext_id__c" : "123",
            "AccountId" : "001i000002CPZlD"
        }
    }]
}
```

I have received following error message for child objects as                                      **errorCode: METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
message: HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET,POST**

Comment: please share what you have tried (code examples preferably) and link any documentation you might have found referencing the limitation you mention as indicated in [ask] . Thanks!

Comment: please update your question and add this, rather than in the comment. ;)

Comment: @glls I have updated question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You might also find one of the REST API [composite resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm) useful where you want to both update a known record and upsert some potentially new records.

With [Composite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) you could update the Opportunity in the first subrequest and then upsert the child records in further subrequests (up to a maximum of 25 subrequests).

It would be something like the following (roughly done by hand):

```
{
    "allOrNone" : true,
    "compositeRequest" : [{
        "method" : "PATCH",
        "url" : "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Account/0016300000NOteE",
        "referenceId" : "UpdatedAccount",
        "body" : {  
            "Name" : "SampleAccount",
            "Phone" : "1234567890"
        }
    },{
        "method" : "PATCH",
        "referenceId" : "NewContact",
        "url" : "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Contact/",
        "body" : {  
            "lastname" : "Smith",
            "title" : "President",
            "email" : "sample@salesforce.com",
            "AccountId" : "@{UpdatedAccount.id}"
        }
    },{
        "method" : "PATCH",
        "referenceId" : "NewContact2",
        "url" : "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Contact/",
        "body" : {  
            "lastname" : "Evans",
            "title" : "Vice President",
            "email" : "sample@salesforce.com",
            "AccountId" : "@{UpdatedAccount.id}"
        }
    },{
        "method" : "PATCH",
        "referenceId" : "JunctionRecord",
        "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/AccountContactJunction__c",
        "body" : {  
            "Name" : "Test Opty",
            "StageName" : "Prospecting",
            "CloseDate" : "2018-03-19",
            "AccountId" : "@{UpdatedAccount.id}"
        }
    }]
}
```

Note that the [upserts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm?search_text=upsert) should include the external ID field name and value in the nested urls.

Comment: @ DanielBallinger Thanks for your response.My question is upsert related records and update parent record. In above example I need to update account and upsert contacts and opportunity.

Comment: @crmsj You will want the REST composite resource then. It can update the the Account and then upsert both the related Contacts and Opportunities. (Up to 25 subrequests in total).

Comment: @ DanielBallinger I got error message using patch for child objects in composite resource.  errorCode: METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
message: HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET,POST

Comment: @crmsj Did you follow my note that the PATCHes also needed to define the external ID field name and value in the URLs? The hand written example is missing that.